# Associating a user with an input

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I'm attempting to be able to `SELECT` users that have chosen players and output the players into input fields. I am setting up a draft type style page. So I need all of the users who are drafting to appear and then under them 13 rows for players. I then want to be able to `INSERT` players under their names and submit them, so that when I submit them the player is associated with that user and that row# (pick number). As of now only one column of inputs are displaying even though I have multiple users in this database table (playersByUser). Then when I try to `INSERT` and submit players in the inputs, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong where only one user is listed and columns with it? Then how could I `INSERT` the players for that user?

Database Table

```
playersByUser
CREATE TABLE `playersByUser` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `playername` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ordering` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `userid` (`userid`),
 CONSTRAINT `playersByUser_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Page code..

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT up.ordering, u.id, u.username, up.playername 
FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN playersByUser AS up ON u.id = up.userid 
WHERE u.group IN (3,4,5)
ORDER BY up.ordering");
if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User/Player SELECT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('User/Player SELECT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$stmt->bind_result($ordering, $userid, $username, $playername);
if(isset($_POST['Add Player'])){ 
//Variables to post in the bind_param 
$insert_user_id = $_POST['user_id']; 
$insert_player = $_POST['playername']; 
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $playername;

}
echo $userid;


$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO playersByUser (user_id, playername) VALUES (?, ?)"); 
if ( false===$stmt2 ) { 
    die('Player Insert prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error)); 
} 
if(!$stmt2->bind_param('is', $insert_user_id, $insert_player)) { 
    // Check errors for binding parameters 
        die('Player Insert bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error)); 
    } 
if(!$stmt2->execute()) { 
        die('Player Insert execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error)); 
    } 
} 
$playerArray = array(); 

//$userid => $insert_player 
//);
?>
        <form action="" method="POST"> 
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    $playersArray[$row['userid']]=$row['playername'];
?>
    <div class="draftResultsWrap"> 
        <div class="inline"> 
        <?php echo "<div>" . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . "</div>"; ?> 
        </div> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray . $userid; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='1'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='2'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='3'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='4'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='5'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='6'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='7'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='8'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='9'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='10'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='11'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='12'/> 
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo playerArray; ?>" class="draftBorder" value='13'/> 
        </div> 
<?php 
} 
?> 
            <button type="submit" method="POST" name="Add Player">Submit Changes</button> 
        </form>
```